# how to view panel which opens while storyboard is active?

Tags: xcode

By mistake the panel which appears on left while clicking the storyboard has disappeared. I want to view it again, How can I bring it back on storyboard. I have attached the [image] for clarification. Kindly help we with this.

Comment: Down alone the bottom status bar (of the story board view), there is a button (on the left), looks like a box with a line along it's inside/left edge. Click that

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank u..

Answer (score 2):

You can expand (/collapse) it by clicking on the small button in the footerbar (see my screenshot).

[image]